# A simple question about functions of sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

Given $A=\{a,b,c\}, \; B=\{1,2,3\}$ and $f:A \to B \;$ given by $f(a)=1, \; f(b)=2$, does $f(A)=f(\{a,b\})=\{1,2\}$?

Comment: You haven't specified what $f(c)$ is.

Comment: This notational question really depends on context.  In one sense, $f(A)$ and $f(\{a, b \})$ don't exist because $A \notin A$ and $\{a, b \} \notin A$ and $\operatorname{domain}(f)=A$.  But notation is often abused in the manner you're suggesting.  Also, describing $f$ as a function $f:A \to B$ is usually understood to mean that $f$ is defined on all of $A$, but you haven't defined $f(c)$.

Comment: @user76284: I certainly dispute your use of "usually". The very page you linked goes on to say "When there is no risk of confusion, $f[A]$ is simply written as $f(A)$. This convention is a common one; the intended meaning must be inferred from the context."

Comment: @GregMartin Do you think that's equally true for subsets of the domain, as in the OP?

Comment: @mjc: Yes. (The page linked in user76284's comment has "image of a subset" in its title.)

Answer (score 2):

No, as $f(c)$ is unspecified, you can just say that $$\{1,2\} \subseteq f[A]$$

and no more on the current data. Of course, $f[\{a,b\}]=\{1,2\}$ is true, we don't need $f(c)$ to compute it.

Comment: My fault—I misread the question and thought there was only one equality to prove.